# Duplicate pages / content loading with Isotope filtering & InfiniteScroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

Firstly I'm a PHP and Javascript Novice and have had someone help create this code for me to work with Wordpress. The problem I am having is it loads a duplicate set of posts when it reaches the bottom. I've searched hi and low for an indication of what might be wrong with the code.

The PHP that loads the post type.

```
<?php
$paged = isset($_REQUEST['page'])?$_REQUEST['page']: 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpsc-product', 'posts_per_page' => 24, 'post_status' =>      'publish', 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'title','order' => 'ASC' );  
if($search) {
$productIds = $wpdb->get_col("select DISTINCT ID from {$wpdb->posts} where post_type =      'wpsc-product' AND post_title  LIKE '%".$search."%' ");
 $args{'post__in'} = ($productIds)?$productIds:'no-data';
}
?>
<div id="container">
<?php       
$loop = query_posts( $args ); 
if( have_posts()) {
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  
//wpsc_the_product_permalink().
$wpsc_product_category = get_the_product_category($post->ID);
$temporary = '';
$classname = '';
if($wpsc_product_category):
foreach($wpsc_product_category  as $value) {
$ParentCategory = $tempParentStorage["{$value->parent}"];
$temporary .= "{$value->slug} ";
$classname .= ($ParentCategory)? " $ParentCategory {$value->slug} ":" {$value->slug}";
}
endif;
?>

<div style='display:none' class="products<?php echo $classname; ?>" data-symbol="<?php     the_title(); ?>" data-category="<?php echo $temporary; ?>" ><a href="<?php echo          wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>" > 
<p><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium'); ?></p>
<p class='product_title' ><?php the_title(); ?></p>
 </a>    
 </div>

 <?php 
 endwhile;
?>  
 </div><!--//container-->   


<?php if(!$search) { ?>
<div id='page_nav' >
<a href='?page=2'></a>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php }
 else {
echo '<div class="products>No Product found</div>';
 }
$totalPages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
wp_reset_query();   
?>
```

Here's the javascript code so far:

```
    <script language='javascript' >
    jQuery(function($){
   //IMPLEMENTING THE ISOTOPE PLUGIN
// modify Isotope's absolute position method
 var $container = $('#container');

var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

 $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ( !$this.hasClass('iam_child_category') ) {
        if(!$this.hasClass('iam_child_of_child_category')) {
              $('.child_filters li').removeClass('child_active_class').addClass('child_inactive_class');
              $('.iam_child_category').removeClass('selected');
        }
    }

    if ( !$this.hasClass('iam_child_of_child_category') ) {
      $('.child_filters_child li').removeClass('child_active_class').addClass('child_inactive_class');
      $('.iam_child_of_child_category').removeClass('selected');
    }

    // don't proceed if already selected
    /*if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }*/

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    $(selector + '_child_li').removeClass('child_inactive_class').addClass('child_active_class');

    if(selector == '*') {
        $('.products').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('.products').hide();
        $(selector).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    return false;

 });



var currentPage = 1;
var lastPage = (<?php echo $totalPages; ?> == 0)?1:<?php echo $totalPages; ?>;   

//call the Infinite Scroll plugin via jQuery

$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.products',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more products to load.',
        img: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif',
        msgText : 'Loading...'

      }
    },



    function( newElements ) {
      currentPage++;            
      if(currentPage == lastPage) { 
        jQuery(window).unbind('.infscr');   
        return false;
      }

      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      // ensure that images load before adding to Isotope layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container('.insert', $newElems );
      });
    }
);

 });


//IMPLEMENTING THE INVIEW PLUGIN

jQuery(document).on("inview", ".products", function(e) {

  $("#container .products").each(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('loaded')) {
        $this.addClass('loaded');
        $this.css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1*e).fadeIn('medium');

    }
   });

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. I needed to specify my "Posts Page" in the Reading settings.